# Can't set focus on an input when document.activeElement is body (or null)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, focus, tabindex

**Quick context:**
I have a list of textboxes, and for each one, the user enters a number in, then on blur of that textbox (user hits <kbd>TAB</kbd>), if the number meets certain criteria, there's a hidden dropdown next to it that gets unhidden, and then focused.

**Problem:**
When the user reaches the last textbox and hits tab, because the dropdown is hidden at that point, the user has reached the last focus-able element, and so the active element becomes the body or null (for more info, see [Mozilla's documentation on document.activeElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/activeElement)). The problem is - once this happens, calling `focus()` on any element on the page doesn't do anything.

**Example:**
[Here's a codepen I created](http://s.codepen.io/joelbyrd/debug/vxzdzG/XxkVwDYJpmeM) where you can see this behavior. After opening that codepen link (preferrably in Chrome), open your developer tools console. Click on the 2nd (middle) textbox, then hit <kbd>TAB</kbd>. Watch your console - after 1 second, the current active element will be logged (you can see it will say #input-3), and the console will say "getting ready to focus on #input-1"...", then after another 2 seconds, the code will try to set the focus on the first textbox (#input-1). It does so successfully when it's on a focus-able element. BUT, if you click on the last textbox and hit <kbd>TAB</kbd>, it will say that the active element is body, and then it will try to focus on #input-1, but nothing will happen.

So what's the issue, and how do I programmatically set focus on an element when document.activeElement is body or null?

Answer (score 1):

This depends on whether there is a reason why the focus would have to actually leave the element. Your codepen uses the keydown event, which is triggered before the blur happens. This is early enough to prevent the focus shift with `event.preventDefault()` (synchronuously, no timeout!):

```
$('input').on('keydown', function(event) {
    if(/* is this a keypress that would change focus? */ &&
       /* are criteria fullfilled? */) {
          event.preventDefault();
          $(/* target element */).focus();
   }
)}
```

This is a bit convoluted, and if you don't care about Firefox compatibility, could be written with the `focusout` event, which triggers before focus leaves the element:

```
$('input').on('focusout', function(event) {
    if(/* are criteria fullfilled? */) {
          $(/* target element */).focus();
   }
)}
```

Incidentally, the `focusout` event has finally landed in the latest Firefox version (52): http://caniuse.com/#search=focusout